# Can you store/convert int values in bool variables?

Tags: c++, types, boolean

I want to read a file which consists of ones and zeroes in each line. How do can I store a `false` in any `bool` variable after reading `0` from the file.

Answer (score 6):

Just read into a boolean variable:

```
bool b;
file >> b;
```

where file is your input file stream. 1's will be converted to true, 0's to false.

If you have read into a string, the obvious way to do the conversion is to look at the first character:

```
string s = .... // populate
bool b = s[0] != '0';
```

but I can't see why you would read into a string if what you really want is a bool.

Comment: i have made tokens of the line from file then.

Comment: @shak Sorry, don't understand that.

Comment: i am making sub strings of each line. so how to store from sting to bool , do i have to convert it to int first.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool b = (variableFromFile != 0);
```

Comment: What about `variable != 0` to keep the nonzero-is-true convention?

Comment: Sneaky... time... page... latency... meh